# Is it possible to use CLI along with GUI?

Tags: user-interface, ide, nuget, command-line-interface, visual-studio-2019

I've read a lot about advantages(speed and flexibility for example) of using .NET Command-line interface so i tried it. I created new ASP.NET Web Api project via PowerShell. It was all good until i wanted to install some Nuget packages. I could not do it in the IDE(VS2019) because the Nuget manager is disabled(package menager console gives me 'No default project). I added Entity Framework package using CLI but first i had to created new solution(using CLI) to the project for some reason. Now to make migration i need to use commands for EF... how is it more flexible than using GUI? It seems for me it's one or another.
My question: how do you guys use CLI? Is there a really good reason to use it?

Comment: Did you use dotnet command to create a new net core project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use CLI along with GUI?

Actually, it can be done and since you want to use CLI to create a project the same as GUI does(have a `xxx.sln file`). Since dotnet command line is quite simple to create a project but creating it as VS IDE does(xxxx.csproj with SLN files and all levels of projects) requires a further command like these:

**1)** use cmd to cd a folder called `Project` and then type this:

```
dotnet new mvc -o <Solution_Name>/<Project_Name> -n <Project_Name>
```

Then create a solution folder and the project but it lacks the `<Solution_Name>.sln` file. And you should use [dotnet sln](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-sln) command.

**2)** create the a file named `<Solution_Name>.sln` under the Solution folder and add these in that file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.28701.123
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
```

Then CMD:

```
cd <Solution_Name>
dotnet sln add <Solution_Name>.sln <Project_Name>\<Project_Name>.csproj
```

**3)** Then it will created as the GUI does.

**Besides**, CLI is simple and convenient(apply for a single project) but if should be as GUI does(a solution contains several projects), it needs to do some extra operation like some other commands, by GUI, it will automatically be created without any steps.

**In addition**, if you want to install a nuget package by CLI, you could use [dotnet add package command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-dotnet-cli#install-a-package) without install it in GUI, like this:

**CMD**

`dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json -v 12.0.1`

**Update 1**

**In fact**, each has its advantages and disadvantages, the score situation to deal with.

To create a single project and do something about the current project，using **CLI** is more convenient. It takes a lot less of the computer's system resources and it can react quickly and improve performance. However, if it involves multiple complex projects, and strive to operate on multiple projects, because **CLI** is too direct and not as visual as **GUI**, easy to operate, it is too complicated to be suitable for novices.

For more comparisons, you can refer to [this link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000619.htm) for more detailed info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Answering the question: yes  i used dotnet commands to create a new net core project, add sln file and packages. Ok i see, so you can make project created via CLI works like GUI created one. I still don's get how using CLI is more convinet than GUI though.

Comment: Actually, to create a single project and do something about the current project，using CLI is more convenient. It takes a lot less of the computer's system resources and it can react quickly and improve performance. However, if it involves multiple complex projects, and strive to operate on multiple projects, because cli is too direct and not as graphical as GUI graphical, it is too complicated to be suitable for novices. In fact, each has its advantages and disadvantages, the score situation to deal with.